# Как в np.where обратиться к своему предыдущему значению?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Таблица:

```
| Curr | Prev |
| --- | --- |
| 174 | 181 |
| 174 | 174 |
| 174 | 174 |
| 174 | 174 |
| 174 | 174 |
| 174 | 174 |
| 183 | 174 |
| 183 | 183 |
| 183 | 183 |
| 183 | 183 |
| 177 | 183 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 177 | 177 |
| 184 | 177 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
| 184 | 184 |
```

Код:

```
x=pd.np.where(Location['Curr']>Location['Prev'],Location['Curr'],#x[-1])
```

Как в np.where обратиться к своему предыдущему значению (x[-1])?

Хочу получить наподобие этого:

```
A=[]   
for i in range(1,len(Location)):          
    if Location['Curr'].iloc[i]>Location['Prev'].iloc[i]:
        A.append(Location['Curr'].iloc[i])
    else:
        if len(A)>0:
            A.append(A[-1])
```

Comment: что значит обратиться ? что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: Обратиться как в обычном цикле. Хочу в случае False добавить предыдущее значение х(последнее).

Comment: Предыдущее значение чего? Какого столбца?

Comment: Самого х. Переменной которой присваиваем значение.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я обновил вопрос и что хочу получить.

Comment: Тот кусок кода, который вы добавили - нерабочий (`IndexError: list index out of range`) и не позволяет понять что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: @MaxU, обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то, вероятно, такое решение будет работать:

```
res = Location.copy()
res.loc[1:,"Curr"] = res.loc[1:,"Curr"].where(df["Curr"]>df["Prev"], np.nan, axis=0)
res["Curr"] = res["Curr"].fillna(method="ffill")
```

res:

```
     Curr  Prev
0   174.0   181
1   174.0   174
2   174.0   174
3   174.0   174
4   174.0   174
5   174.0   174
6   183.0   174
7   183.0   183
8   183.0   183
9   183.0   183
10  183.0   183
11  183.0   177
12  183.0   177
13  183.0   177
14  183.0   177
15  183.0   177
16  183.0   177
17  183.0   177
18  183.0   177
19  183.0   177
20  184.0   177
21  184.0   184
22  184.0   184
23  184.0   184
24  184.0   184
25  184.0   184
26  184.0   184
27  184.0   184
28  184.0   184
29  184.0   184
```